# LinkedIn API Key and Secret - Permissions

Tags: linkedin-api, marketo

What permission level do I need to have to get access to the API Key and Secret. Do one have be at least be a campaign manager or does being a viewer suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to see the LinkedIn data integration API Keys of an adAccount one have to have at least the “Creative Manager” access permission for the account in question. Out of the 4 available permissions, “Creative Manager” is the second one, right above “Viewer”.

[image: LinkedIn adAccount access permissions]